# ListView System.StackOverflowException in UWP

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

My listview has  more 6153 row datas.

This line get "System.StackOverflowException" after 428. row

```
            if (root.ListView.Items != null && !root.ListView.SelectedItems.Contains(root.ListView.Items[index]))
            {
                ObservableCollection[index].Status = "Passed";
                index++;
                DownloadList();//for recursive
                return;
            }
```

Source of ListView is `ObservableCollection<>`
What is the cause of this problem? Normally code works fine

Comment: How is this called? Can you provide the rest of this method? StackOverflowExceptions are the result of too many nested method calls. Somewhere in your code, you probably have a method being called many, many more times than you think.

Comment: After the edit: What is `DownloadList()`? Are you positive that's not causing a case of infinite recursion somehow?

Comment: Why `//for recursive` ? Anyhow, that is the clear cause of the stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're using recursion to go across your listview.

Would

```
while(root.ListView.Items != null 
      && !root.ListView.SelectedItems.Contains(root.ListView.Items[index]){
       ObservableCollection[index].Status = "Passed";
       index++;
}

return;
```

not work? If you're doing the above you're making 6000+ Stack frames, and at 1 MB a piece you're quickly consuming memory and it doesn't appear that you need the state that recursion allows